# React Native isPressed changes style for all the elements in the loop. How to change only one elements style?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, loops

The below code changes style to itemStyles.listItemPressed to all the elements in the Item loop. I need to have only one element change the style on pressing the container. Down below i have my second way of tryng to do that. But in the second try the pressed styles apply and stay there after i let go of my finger. I need the style to change back to default after i dont press on the screen.

```
const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = React.useState(false);

const [selectBtn, setSelectBtn] = React.useState(null);
    
function onPressIn() {
    setIsPressed(true);
}

function onPressOut() {
    setIsPressed(false);
}

 <View>
                    {options.map((option) => (
                        <Pressable
                            onPress={onPress}
                            onPressIn={onPressIn}
                            onPressOut={onPressOut}
                            style={[
                                itemStyles.listItem,
                                isPressed && itemStyles.listItemPressed,
                            ]}
                        >
                            <Item
                                checked={option.value === value}
                                key={option.value}
                                label={option.label}
                                disabled={disabled}
                                onPress={() => onChange(option.value)}
                            />
                        </Pressable>
                    ))}
                </View>
```

**Second try**

```
       return (
            <View style={style}>
                <View>
                    {options.map((option, index) => (
                        <Pressable
                            style={[
                                itemStyles.listItem,
                                { backgroundColor: selectBtn === index ? 'red' : 'gray' },
                            ]}
                            onPressIn={() => {
                                setSelectBtn(index);
                            }}
                            onPressOut={null}
                            onPress={onPress}
                        >
                            <Item
                                checked={option.value === value}
                                key={option.value}
                                label={option.label}
                                disabled={disabled}
                                onPress={() => onChange(option.value)}
                            />
                        </Pressable>
                    ))}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

**My options array**

```
 options={[
                    { label: "Value", value: "value" },
                    { label: "Value", value: "value2" },
                    { label: "Value", value: "value3" },
                    { label: "Value", value: "value4" },
                    { label: "Value", value: "value5" },
                ]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you know which elements index you want to change style when onPressed

Hey you can do something like this :
UPDATED LINK
https://snack.expo.dev/uRUZuvibJ check out this

```js
import {React,useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,Pressable } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

const data = ["hey","india","anime","manga","arsenal"]

export default function App() {

  const [selected,setSelect] = useState([])

  const handlePress = (index) => {
    let existingState = [...selected];
    if(existingState.includes(index)){
      existingState = existingState.filter(item => item !== index)
      setSelect(existingState)
    } else {
      existingState.push(index)
      setSelect(existingState)
    }
  }

  const renderItem = (item,index) => {
    const isSelected = selected.includes(index)
    return(
      <Pressable style={isSelected?styles.press:styles.unpress}  onPressIn={() => handlePress(index)} onPressOut={() => handlePress(index)} >
      <Text>{item}</Text>
      </Pressable>
   )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     {data.map((item,index) => {
       return renderItem(item,index)
     })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
   unpress:{
     height:40,
     width:'100%',
     backgroundColor:'red',
     flex:1
   },
   press:{
     height:40,
     width:'100%',
     backgroundColor:'green',
     flex:1
   }
});
```

Hope it helps :)

[image]

Comment: I need to change the style on every element i press

Comment: ahhh got it , wait ill share an expo snack :)

Comment: thanks for the code but i think i didnt express my problem clearly. If i click your red container it should change to green and when i let go of the click it should change back to red. Not changing the color with two clicks

Comment: that ill modify dont worry, give me 30 mins

Comment: @Codeanorr please check , update

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this problem that have elements with multiple properties and states by using `useReducer`: https://snack.expo.dev/@zvona/state-of-multiple

Here's the full code from the snack of handling state through useReducer:

```
import { useState, useReducer } from 'react';
import { Text, Pressable, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const options = [{ value: 'first' }, { value: 'second' }, { value: 'third' }];
const initialState = { ...options };

const App = () => {
  const selectedReducer = (state, { type, index }) => {
    const { selected, pressed } = state[index];
    const newState = { ...state };

    switch (type) {
      case 'pressIn':
        newState[index].pressed = true;
        break;
      case 'pressOut':
        newState[index].pressed = false;
        break;
      case 'press':
        newState[index].selected = !selected;
        break;
      default:
        console.warn('invalid type');
        break;
    }

    return newState;
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(selectedReducer, initialState);

  const getStyling = (index) => [
    styles.pressableStyle,
    state[index].selected && styles.listItemSelected,
    state[index].pressed && styles.listItemPressed,
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        {options.map((option, index) => (
          <Pressable
            onPressIn={() => dispatch({ type: 'pressIn', index })}
            onPressOut={() => dispatch({ type: 'pressOut', index })}
            onPress={() => dispatch({ type: 'press', index })}
            style={getStyling(index)}>
            <Text>{option.value}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        ))}
      </View>{' '}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },

  pressableStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
  },

  listItemPressed: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },

  listItemSelected: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use some other logic for this.

But what  have done with a similar problem where. I had to change color of an element in a loop on hover.

I made a separate component for the item inside the loop on which i had to apply changes.

Then in that separate component i had a state like `isPressed`. Now what it does is that each element in the loop have its own personal state for isPressed so i can check it for each individual item without affecting other elements in the loop.

For Example:
App.js

```
function App(){
  return <div>
  {someArray.map((item)=><Component ...props... />)}
</div>
}
```

Component.js

```
function Component(){
const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);
return 
 <someTag onClick={()=>setIsPressed(true)}  style={{color:isPressed ? 'blue' : 'red'}} >....</somTag>

}
```

You can also handle function on click in App.js then you have to pass function as a prop to Component and onClick in Component it will call props.sentFunction ...